# i_zone[7] how to stand for 512 blocks?

Tags: c, kernel

I'm reading the kernel of Linux 0.12, the codes in inode.c:

```
static int _bmap(struct m_inode * inode,int block,int create)
{
    struct buffer_head * bh;
    int i;

    if (block<0)
        panic("_bmap: block<0");
    if (block >= 7+512+512*512)
        panic("_bmap: block>big");
    if (block<7) {
        if (create && !inode->i_zone[block])
            if (inode->i_zone[block]=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
                inode->i_ctime=CURRENT_TIME;
                inode->i_dirt=1;
            }
        return inode->i_zone[block];
    }
block -= 7;
    if (block<512) {
        if (create && !inode->i_zone[7])
            if (inode->i_zone[7]=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
                inode->i_dirt=1;
                inode->i_ctime=CURRENT_TIME;
            }
        if (!inode->i_zone[7])
            return 0;
        if (!(bh = bread(inode->i_dev,inode->i_zone[7])))
            return 0;
        i = ((unsigned short *) (bh->b_data))[block];
        if (create && !i)
            if (i=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
                ((unsigned short *) (bh->b_data))[block]=i;
                bh->b_dirt=1;
            }
        brelse(bh);
        return i;
    }
block -= 512;
    if (create && !inode->i_zone[8])
        if (inode->i_zone[8]=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
            inode->i_dirt=1;
            inode->i_ctime=CURRENT_TIME;
        }
    if (!inode->i_zone[8])
        return 0;
    if (!(bh=bread(inode->i_dev,inode->i_zone[8])))
        return 0;
    i = ((unsigned short *)bh->b_data)[block>>9];
    if (create && !i)
        if (i=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
            ((unsigned short *) (bh->b_data))[block>>9]=i;
            bh->b_dirt=1;
        }
    brelse(bh);
    if (!i)
        return 0;
    if (!(bh=bread(inode->i_dev,i)))
        return 0;
    i = ((unsigned short *)bh->b_data)[block&511];
    if (create && !i)
        if (i=new_block(inode->i_dev)) {
            ((unsigned short *) (bh->b_data))[block&511]=i;
            bh->b_dirt=1;
        }
    brelse(bh);
    return i;
}
```

I konw that i_zone[0] ~ i_zone[6] can store a block. But the i_zone how to 
stand for 512 blocks?  and i_zone[8] how to stand for 512*512 blocks ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i_zone[0]` through `i_zone[6]` store the addresses of 7 data blocks.  These are "direct" blocks.

`i_zone[7]` stores the address of a block which itself stores the addresses of 512 data blocks.  This is an "indirect" block.

`i_zone[8]` stores the address of a block which itself stores the address of 512 indirect blocks, which each store the addresses of 512 data blocks.  This is a "double indirect" block.

Comment: thank you. "i_zone[7] stores the address of a block which itself stores the addresses of 512 data blocks." the addresses is the start address of the 512 blcoks ?

Comment: @lxgeek: The block addressed by `i_zone[7]` is an array of 512 block addresses.